I want to add some packages to the Ubuntu iso file
I want to add some packages to the Ubuntu .iso file(except the ones default coming) so then I want to can use the packages I install the Ubuntu and so with that experience I want to add more configurations to the .iso file. I'm going to extract the .iso file and manually change the files and again build the .iso . can I do the work that way or should I use some tools.

Have you looked at any of the documentation?  How much did you understand? or where were you confused etc.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization etc.

This question is similar to: How I can customize the Ubuntu Live ISO installer using Cubic (add, remove, and upgrade packages and set language)?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I find it easier just to run a script with all the additional apps I want, after install. Unless installing into many totally identical systems, modifying ISO seems like a lot more work.

agree with oldfred create a post install script. Saves you a lot of time since you can re-use and easily adjust it for a next OS.

You can use ubuntu-image to build your own iso which is derived from original build process and you can cutomise it to have additional packages
The server image config is here - https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu-images/tree/ubuntu-server-pc-amd64.yaml
You can customise it to build your own image or iso
